# BigQuery string comparison and adjustment with replace/trim

Tags: replace, google-bigquery

I tried to accommodate in BigQuery for inputs with bad spacing.
However, I keep getting weird results, basically saying that  `abc <> abc`.

Can anyone explain how this is possible? 
I tried to adjust this by using `replace` and `rtrim` but none of them served the purpose.

Thank you

```
SELECT o = t,o, t, length(o) as lon_o, length(t) as len_t
from
(select replace('abc                                                                ',' ','') o,
'abc' as t)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able easily reproduce your case by having (for example) few `tabs` inside that string instead of spaces -

[image]

visually they look exactly alike - but first row has 64 spaces in it whereas second row has 5 tabs and 44 spaces. In Web UI each tab occupy 2 char-places so that is why total 5 tabs + 44 spaces look like 64 spaces (exactly as in first row)

To address this - you can use REGEXP_REPLACE instead of REPLACE
Using REGEXP_REPLACE allows you to 'remove' all white spaces, as in example below (the only difference here is in second row - using REGEXP_REPLACE instead of REPLACE and use of `r'\s'` instead `' '`

[image]

And, finally - if to get back to first example  - the good way of seeing what actually makes those 8 chars vs. 3 chars in result's `lon_o` is to switch from `Table` view`to`JSON` view as below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me
[image]

Check if you don't have hidden ASCII chars in your text which might be causing this for example [HEX 80](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html)